# VS Addin - How to add controls to IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have created a VS addin.
I'd like to interact with the user by adding a dropbox above the Solution Explorer.
I can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See a code example of "[VSSDK IDE Sample: Combo Box](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VSSDK-IDE-Sample-Combo-Box-e9f13c01)", it covers:

> - Adding a Drop Down Combo to Visual Studio and handling it
> - Adding an
> - Index Combo to Visual Studio and handling it  Adding a MRU Combo to
> - Visual Studio and handling it  Adding a Dynamic Combo to Visual
> - Studio and handling it  Controling the programmatic name of the
>     combo    box commands by placing the commands within a menu ("Tools"
>     in our    case) of the main menu bar.

I believe you should start investigating VSIP (Visual Studio Integration SDK and Package information:

- [Visual Studio Integration SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336.aspx)